# Post method with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

I would like to send the data to another php page using javascript but it does not work as expected.
Let just say I have the form:

```
<form id="myForm">
        <label for="name">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        <label for="pass">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
        <button id="submit" type="submit" >OK</button>
</form>
```

and the script:

```
   const myForm = document.getElementById('submit');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData(this);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'getData.php', true);
xhr.onload = function () {
    // do something to response
    console.log(this.responseText);
};
xhr.send(data);
});
```

The php file is unable to recieve the data at the moment. How can it fix with ajax or any other equivalent code?

Comment: You need to fix the first JS line; it's supposed to get the form, not the submit button.

Comment: Thank you very much! but i just test it and it gave me Cors error which does not make sense to me?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @ChrisG It is my bad, the header should not be in local file. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make change in button

```
<button id="submit" type="button" onclick="sendData()" >OK</button>
```

Then add javascript function.

```
<script>
  function sendData(){

    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var password = document.getElementById("pass");

     if (name) {
         $.ajax({  
             type:"POST",  
             url:"path-to-php-file.php",  
             data:'name='+name+'&pass='+password,
             success:function(data){  
                alert(data);                            
             }  
      });   
  }
</script>
```

Then create php file where you will get data.
path-to-php-file.php

```
<?php 
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $password = $_POST['pass'];

  echo $name .'--'.$password; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell exactly what is the problem without looking at your php code.
Maybe there is something wrong with the `Content-Type` header.

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData(this); // Here 'this' will not work, you gotta loop through the inputs and append them to the FormData object.

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    // do something
}
xhr.open('POST', 'getData.php', true);
// the default content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "<content type here>")
xhr.send(data);
});
```

### Extra

What I suggest is in your case you won't really need a form element here. You could make the button a normal button and make the form a div(not special benefit, just for clean code). Assign a function to the `onclick` event of the button and loop through the inputs and append them to the form data(if the content  type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) object and send it to the server.Use this method if you have a complex form like a interactive form like Google or Microsoft have.

And also you do not want to use preventDefault() method if you follow my method.

This is what most professionals would do.